# Get Property Value of Nested Classes is always null

Tags: c#, reflection

I have following two classes

```
public class Family
{
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Family Child { get; set; }

}
```

I have an instance of Employee class as follows.

```
 Employee employee = new Employee();
 employee.Name = "Ram";
 employee.Id = 77;
 employee.Child = new Family() { ChildName = "Lava" };
```

I have a method which gets the property value based on the property name as follows:

```
public static object GetPropertyValue(object src, string propName)
{
  string[] nameParts = propName.Split('.');

 if (nameParts.Length == 1)
  {
    return src.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
  }

foreach (String part in nameParts)
{
    if (src == null) { return null; }

    Type type = src.GetType();

    PropertyInfo info = type.GetRuntimeProperty(part);

    if (info == null)
    { return null; }

    src = info.GetValue(src, null);
   }
   return src;
}
```

In the above method,when I try to get property value of nested class like

```
GetPropertyValue(employee, "employee.Child.ChildName")
```

or

```
GetPropertyValue(GetPropertyValue(employee, "Family"), "ChildName"
```

doesn't return any value because `type.GetRuntimeProperty(part)` is always null.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem lies in this line:

```
foreach (String part in nameParts)
```

Because you are iterating over each part of nameParts, you are also iterating over "employee", which of course is not a valid property.

Try either this:

```
foreach (String part in nameParts.Skip(1))
```

Or calling the method like this:

```
GetPropertyValue(employee, "Child.ChildName")
```

(Notice no "employee.", because you already pass in an employee)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case is that when you split the string `employee.Child.ChildName`, the "employee" is the first part. However, `employee` is not a property of the source i.e. `Employee` Class.

Try this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.Name = "Ram";
        employee.Id = 77;
        employee.Child = new Family() { ChildName = "Lava" };
        GetPropertyValue(employee, "employee.Child.ChildName");

    }


    public class Family
    {
        public string ChildName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Family Child { get; set; }

    }

    public static object GetPropertyValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        string[] nameParts = propName.Split('.');

        if (nameParts.Length == 1)
        {
            return src.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
        }
        nameParts = nameParts.Skip(1).ToArray();
        foreach (String part in nameParts)
        {
            if (src == null) { return null; }

            Type type = src.GetType();

            PropertyInfo info = type.GetRuntimeProperty(part);

            if (info == null)
            { return null; }

            src = info.GetValue(src, null);
        }
        return src;
    }
```

Here, i have skipped the first part of the string i.e. "employee". However, you can solve the problem by passing `Child.ChildName`

Answer (score -1):

This question is around 2 years old, but I found a another working solution for you question, which is easy to understand. If you initialize the object in calling calss constructor you can use dot(.) notation to assign or read property. Example -

```
public class Family{
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Family Child { get; set; }

    public Employee(){
        Child = new Family();
    }
}

Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.Family.ChildName = "Nested calss attribute value";
```

Comment: You can do that in OPs example as well (no need for a constructor), however, the question was about why his reflection method didn't work.